# Xcode project doesn't recognize podfile properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I've just added this pod to my project:

[image: My Podfile]

and have run `pod install` in terminal which looked fine too.

```
Charless-MBP:BloQuery charleswesleycho$ pod install
Updating local specs repositories
Analyzing dependencies
Downloading dependencies
Using IPInsetLabel (1.3.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
Sending stats
```

And I'm also using the  `.xcworkspace`

[image: Here they are, I am using the white one]

But when I try to use the new functionality that this pod is supposed to bring Xcode complains:

[image: Why Xcode...]
 even though I did import into the class and  `Xcode`  even autocompleted when I was typing it in.  Any ideas of why my pod is not connected?

This is the pod : https://github.com/control/IPInsetLabel

[image: ITS IMPORTED!]

Comment: Can you show the type of `questionTextLabel` that you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the type of `self.questionTextLabel` is `UILabel`. However `UILabel` does not have properties like `insets` and `verticalTextAlignment`. These are properties added by `IPInsetLabel`.

So once you make your `self.questionTextLabel` of the type `IPInsetLabel`, you will be able to access those properties.

Comment: That sounds right but when I try to change the class of the " questionTextLabel  " in the storyboard there's no autocomplete.  Even when I do change the class Xcode still doesn't recognize the properties.

Comment: So first you have to change the class of your label in storyboard. Plus you have to make an outlet of the new type of label. I am assuming your questionTestLabel's outlet is still of type UILabel and thats why you cant see the properties.